# How to set OpenIdConnect option prompt ="login" from Controller in .net core 2 application?

Tags: azure, openid, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm using a .net core 2 application and have set OpenIDConnect options prompt parameter to consent in ConfigureServices method in Startup.cs

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
     options.prompt ="consent";
}
```

But in the initial login page I want to just use the prompt ="login" without consent screen.

In Controller page

```
            return Challenge(
                   new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = 
                  Url.Action("Index") },
                  OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Is there any way to change the prompt parameter to "login" from controller. In the previous version we could do this using OwinContext.

```
HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Environment.Add("Prompt","login");
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `Items` property to communicate arbitrary parameters:

```
var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    RedirectUri = Url.Action("Index")
};
authenticationProperties.Items["prompt"] = "login";
return Challenge(
    authenticationProperties,
    OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Then you will have to handle the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event, something like this:

```
options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
{
    OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
    {
        if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue("prompt", out string prompt))
        {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = prompt;
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
};
```

It looks in the Items if there is a prompt value given, and if so, replaces the existing value with that.

Comment: Thank you juunas! I had an issue where i needed to distinguish between two different login paths by passing parameters to the provider. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 3):

In ASP.NET Core 3.x you can set the prompt option using:

```
.AddMyTestOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://localhost:6001";
    options.ClientId = "authcodeflowclient";
    options.ClientSecret = "mysecret";
    options.ResponseType = "code";

    // stuff...

    options.Prompt = "consent";
});
```