# Where can I find a code sample for OpenId Connect sign out for c#?

Tags: c#, openid-connect, openid, logout

Security is one of those things that once you set it up, you kinda forget about it, until something doesn't work. I have a .Net Core application that uses OpenId Connect with Azure. The sign in works fine, but we noticed a few days ago that the signout wasn't working. You could sign out of the application, but then login again directly without entering credentials. So, I have been looking around and found out that it's not good enough to clear the cookies and session, you need to go to the "end_session_endpoint" to actually clear the credentials. I have looked in a number of places, but I can't find a simple code example of how to to this. And the code examples I have tried don't seem to work. When I run locally, I can logout and it says it logged me out, but when I start the application again, I am logged in automatically right away. I understand the concept, I just don't know how to do it. Below is what my authentication looks like in the Startup.cs file:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {

            })
            .AddCookie()
            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:OAuth"];
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.UsePkce = false;
                options.Scope.Clear();
                options.Scope.Add("openid");
                options.Scope.Add("email");
                options.SaveTokens = true;
                options.CallbackPath = new PathString(Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Callback"]);
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,                      
                };

                // MetadataAddress represents the Active Directory instance used to authenticate users.
                options.MetadataAddress = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Meta"];

                options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ApplicationId"];
                options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:Password"];

            });
```

Does anyone have a straight forward code example for this?

Comment: This should not be that difficult to figure out, but I still can't find a straightforward code example for this. I've seen plenty of documentation, and plenty of examples that don't actually work, because they are for a product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**RP INITIATED LOGOUT**

This is mostly a case of sending the standard message with these parameters.If I remember rightly, Azure may require the third of these to log you out successfully.

- client_id
- post_logout_redirect_uri
- id_token_hint

**EXAMPLES**

Here is a [C# example](https://github.com/curityio/example-dotnet-openid-connect-client/blob/master/example-dotnet-openid-connect-client/Controllers/LogoutController.cs) that sends this type of request. It uses the older .Net framework, but should be easy to follow.

In .Net Core, you can set a `SignedOutCallbackPath` in the OIDC properties, which must match a `post_logout_redirect_uri` registered against the client in Azure AD. You can then call this code in the controller and it should send the standard mesaage.

```
await HttpContext.SignoutAsync():
```

Personally I find this .NET syntax and C# layer a little unintuitive, but ultimately it is just a wrapper around the standard messages.

My [Azure SPA example](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.azure/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts#L203) does an RP initiated logout, and I can confirm that the above parameters work fine with Azure AD.

**ADVANCED OPTIONS**

Sometimes logout can be a very tricky area to get the best usability behaviour, depending on the provider. In case useful later, another option is to use the `max-age` parameter from [OpenID Connect](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest) during sign in. You then get an `auth_time` claim in the ID token. On the next redirect after auth_time has expired you can use this data to send a `prompt=login` parameter if required, to force the user to re-authenticate. The .NET way to do this is described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50036780/how-to-set-openidconnect-option-prompt-login-from-controller-in-net-core-2-a).

**UPDATE**

Here is what my SPA config looks like, with the post logout redirect URI, to check against your own configuration. RP (relying party) is your C# web app, OP (openid connect provider) is Azure AD (I never liked this type of terminology). The logout mechanics are just focused on removing the SSO cookie that Azure AD sets. Azure AD logout behaviour may not be easy to control fully though, since logout in OAuth technologies can sometimes get complex and involve multiple apps.

[image: azure config]

**TEST OPTION**

One option you could try is logging in and out using [OAuth Tools](https://oauth.tools/), which is useful for troubleshooting this type of problem without needing to write code. Once you get the correct behaviour here, you'll be clearer about what you need to code:

- First find your OpenID Connect metadata URL - this is [my URL](https://login.microsoftonline.com/7f071fbc-8bf2-4e61-bb48-dabd8e2f5b5a/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)
- Next select `Add Environment`, give it a name like `my` and enter the metadata URL - then make sure this environment is selected
- Add https://oauth.tools/callback/code to Azure AD as a redirect URI
- Then select `Code Flow` in OAuth tools, enter your development Azure AD client ID and client secret, then select Run, to trigger a redirect
- Then scroll down and click `Redeem Authorization Code`, which will get tokens, including an ID token which might be needed for logout
- Then run a `Logout Flow`, for which you'll need to set `https://oauth.tools` in Azure AD as the front channel logout URL
- If you can't get logout to work as you'd like, try the `prompt=login` option, which will force a new login

[image: oauth tools]

**Q & A**

1. So OIDC logout is working but a second factor time to live is not.  This is outside the OIDC specs and probably cannot be influenced by code. Try it in a new Incognito browser window and see if you have to enter the second factor. If so then it will be a cookie that you may be able to identify if you trace the HTTP traffic. Look for a configuration setting somewhere that controls this - something similar to the Curity TTL setting in [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/optin-mfa-howto/#configure-opt-in-mfa). If there is no such setting then it may be outside your control.
2. Leftover browser sessions. In some ways if users let other people use their desktop sessions then all bets are off. You can get too hung up on this. Just aim to be as good as other apps. Eg are you as secure as Office 365 itself, Gmail etc?
3. By default (without a post logout redirect URI) the user is dumped back in the Azure login screen, which is typically not what the user wants. Instead a post logout landing screen gives your app control over the UX. A common option is to just display something like `You are signed out, click here to log back in`. In a C# website this would just return a view to the browser.

Comment: First, thanks for responding! I will look at the C# option. In the documentation I have been able to find, it talks about it not being enough to just clear things, you have to direct the user to the logout request in Azure, which matches what you are saying. But you included some extra bits I hadn't seen before. In Azure app reg, I only see an option for Front Channel Logout URL. I've seen screen shots of another field, but I don't see it. Also, I don't understand what the terms RP and OP mean. Remote Process?

Comment: I do agree with you that the .Net Syntax as unintuitive. It makes it look deceptively simple.

Comment: None of that worked. The problem is that we are using Office 365 with the Microsoft Authenticator app. So, for example, I can click the logout button and the site will tell me it's logged me out. But when I shut down the site (local dev) and restart the application, it logs me in right away.

Comment: Well I added some further notes above, in response to your comments. I would focus on messages first, rather than C# code, and hopefully the above notes give you some troubleshooting options.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much for the additional notes. I went through the OAuth tools process and it looked familiar to me. It worked, and didn't work. The first time I log into the application, and I enter my password and such, it fires off a second factor auth to Microsoft Authenticator. I then need to go into my phone and approve the request. As it is with what I've seen, I can log out, but when I go to log back in, that 2 factor auth is bypassed and I'm just logged in. My password is already there.

Comment: So, basically, I can log out, but if someone walks up to my computer, and I haven't locked it, they can click login, and the account selection is already made, and the password is already in there. All they need to do is click through and they are in. How can I clear that 2 factor auth so that when I log out, I need to do the 2 factor in order to log in again? Otherwise, logging out isn't really logging out. Make sense?

Comment: Oh, one other question I have is about your logout path. I see something similar in my Azure. My question is about the path you put in there. It looks like a path to a folder in your application. I'm confused about what exactly that is about? If the end_session_endpoint is what does the logging out, what is that path for, and what code do you put there?

Comment: Added Q & A section above - a few hints there